Is there a list of all multiple-item discount deals on Amazon.ca?
I stumbled onto a "3 for the price of 2" deal while viewing one of the items that were part of the deal, but I can't find a way to see a list of all "multiple-item discount" deals.
They don't seem to be listed in the Deals Store, nor is www.amazon.ca/promotion a valid URL.
Is there a list of all multiple-item discount deals on Amazon.ca?

